# How to disable the user to delete a chart in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

i made a chart on my excel sheet, and i want the user not to be able to delete it...

how can i do it?

I already tried this options from here:

https://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ChartProtection.html

The code is like this:

```
'Draw a chart
Dim rng As range
Dim cht As ChartObject

'Your data range for the chart
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").range("$A$2:$A$100")

'Activate chart
Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Activate

'Populate chart with data
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rng


'Determine type
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.ChartType = xlLineMarkers

'Delete the 5th series
If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 5 Then
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Delete
End If
```

I need something like this:

```
ActiveChart.preventDeleting
```

Now, the protection I had in mind was to prevent the user, from actively deleting the chart....a simple select and remove, or button press delete, or something...

In simple terms, block any attempt to delete the chart...

But, i dont know if this is relevant, but the table can change its range, and the chart should be still able to get updated...

Please let me know, if you need something else...

Also, it does not nessesary need to be a vba code, it can also be a manual solution, I am using MS excel 2007

Thanks...

Comment: Just protect the sheet

Comment: I still need the user to be able to manipulate the data on the sheet....would that work?

Comment: Yes just don't lock the cells

Answer (score 2):

You can protect the chart by protecting the sheet. If you want the user to be able to edit some of the cells, simply right click on the cells that you want to be able to be edited and select `Format Cells -> Protection -> Locked` and make sure this is unchecked.

[image]

Then protect the worksheet via `Review -> Protect Sheet` on the menu bar. This will prevent the deletion of the chart and allow users to continue editing the cell content

Comment: thanks for your time, but once i do that, this error appears, requested shapes are locked for selection, at the following line:     Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Activate, i unlocked the rows that are gonna be changed, also the data required for the chart....but still the error...

Comment: That's because you're now trying to change a protected object. You will need to handle this in your VBA `Worksheet.Unprotect` and `Worksheet.Protect` in the relevant places. Or protect the worksheet via VBA and set the option `UserInterFaceOnly:=True` however, this setting will be lost whenever the workbook is closed so will need to be set each time you open the workbook/sheet